# How can I get the CIDR block of the VPC selected by the user in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I am asking the user to choose an existing VPC:

```
Parameters:
  MyVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
```

Then in my 'Resources' block I am trying to get the CIDR block of that VPC.
When I try this:

```
      - Fn::GetAtt:
        - MyVPC
        - CidrBlock
```

I get:

```
Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource MyVPC
```

Which I understand I guess because technically MyVPC is a parameter not a resource.

So how can I get the CIDR block of the VPC selected by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible.

The `Parameter` is merely a VPC **ID**, not the VPC itself.

The `GetAtt` command is expecting a `Resource` in the template, which is not there.

You would either need to add the CIDR block as another parameter, or create a Lambda-backed [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) that would fetch the information and make it available to the template.